# changing machine Network Adapter Ip lead to SQL Server service failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I configured my sql server to listen on ip:192.168.1.2 but since my machine get IP from DHCP may my last IP be differ from previous one on next start up.
in this situation when sql service wants to start, it cant find previous IP and cant start.

I would like to know ,is there a solution as SQL update itself IPs automatically?or I have to update IPs manually on every start up?

as I saw, when I changed my IPs and restart machine or SQL service it doesn't Modify Ip.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use static IP or Named Pipe?

Comment: Why do you configure SQL to listen to a specific IP if you're using DHCP?

Comment: @SimonLoh I cant use static IP but I dont know anything about Named Pipe and how can connect to remote Server with named pipe.

Comment: @OlaEkdahl I cant use static IP

Comment: @hamed - Instead of using IP, you were using computer name instead, that is named pipe

Comment: @SimonLoh only computer name or something like this : **server=np:\\hostname\pipe\pipeName**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may try Named Pipe?

http://devproconnections.com/database-development/sql-server-performance-tip-favoring-tcpip-over-named-pipes

Are your system hard-coded the IP address and not allowed to be change?

Comment: I want to have remote access to another machine. whether the named pipes are proper solution?

Comment: @hamed What do you mean by "remote access" ? Are you mean RDP in?

Comment: for using named pipes I should enable Named Pipes. whether I must Enable TCP/IP? is there need to determine user pass in connection string?

Comment: remote access means the client and server aren't on same machine

Comment: I found it is impossible to establish a remote access to remote server through named pipes without tcp/ip enabled and configured. if I want to configure tcp/ip I will connect through tcp/ip. as you know I dont want dealing with tcp/ip configuration since problem I said in my question